# Vaadin TextField show validation error without hovering over error indicator

Tags: java, vaadin

I have added a validator to a vaadin text field.

```
usernameField.addValidator(value -> {
    if (value.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        throw new Validator.InvalidValueException("Please enter your username");
    }
});
```

And when user clicks a button, I call validate.

```
try {
    usernameField.validate();
} catch (Validator.InvalidValueException e) {
    usernameField.setValidationVisible(true);
    return;
}
```

When validation fails, vaadin adds an error indicator exclamation mark next to the text field. If I hover over this, the error message `"Please enter your username"` appears as a tooltip.

I need to make the error message visible on the UI, without hovering over the error indicator.

Is there a way to do this without using an additional error message label?

Comment: As far as I know: no :(

Comment: Wild thought: you could show a [notification](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-notifications.html) in your `catch` block. Additionally you could use a singe label to display the error messages like in the [Vaadin 6 form (deprecated in 7)](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin6/-/page/components.form.html) (see first picture)